# Microsoft 365. SMTP. Возможно ли использовать PAT?

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, office365

Мы используем smtp.office365.com для отправки писем. Мы делаем следуеще:

```
  var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", smtpServerPort);
  smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
  smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpServerUsername, smtpServerPassword);
  smtp.EnableSsl = smtpServerSSL;
```

Возможно ли как то использовать не smtpServerUsername и smtpServerPassword, а например как в Azure DevOps Service использовать PAT?

Comment: Возможно, этот вопрос лучше адресовать в службу поддержки Microsoft.